# How do I patch the `pathlib.Path.exists()` method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pathlib

I want to patch the `exists()` method of a `pathlib.Path` object for a unit test but I have problems getting this to work.

What I am trying to do is this:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from pathlib import Path

def test_move_basic():
    p = Path('~/test.py')
    with patch.object(p, 'exists') as mock_exists:
        mock_exists.return_value = True
```

But it fails with:

`AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object attribute 'exists' is read-only`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to use a `Path` object or can you just mock the whole thing?

Comment: I need the `Path` object...

Comment: Don't patch an instance. Patch *classes*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to patch the *class*, not the instance. It is enough to patch the method on the `Path` class, as it defines the `exists` method for the whole of the `pathlib` library (`PosixPath`, `WindowsPath`, `PurePosixPath` and `PureWindowsPath` all inherit the implementation):

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('~/test.py')
>>> with patch.object(Path, 'exists') as mock_exists:
...     mock_exists.return_value = True
...     p.exists()
...
True
>>> with patch.object(Path, 'exists') as mock_exists:
...     mock_exists.return_value = False
...     p.exists()
...
False
>>> with patch.object(Path, 'exists') as mock_exists:
...     mock_exists.return_value = 'Anything you like, actually'
...     p.exists()
...
'Anything you like, actually'
```

The `pathlib` classes use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to keep their memory footprint low, which has the side-effect of their instances not supporting arbitrary attribute assignment.